# How to match a long path among plenty of short versions

Tags: javascript, regex

**SOLUTION IS :**

```
var str = this.path;
var spltd = str.split('/');
var agg = '(?:';
var e = 'Item';
for (i = 0; i < spltd.length-2; i++) { agg += '(?:';}
var newstr = '^(?:\/?'+agg+spltd.join('\/)?')+'::)?'+e;
var regex = new RegExp(newstr);
var check = str.match(regex);
console.log(check); // Works on the good cases, not on the bad
```

### thanks to @Rodrigo López

---

**PROBLEM WAS :**

I'm trying to setup a **research functionality**.

Basically, I have `paths` like :

```
Item    
Path::Item
/Path::Item
Long/Path::Item
/Long/Path::Item
Very/Long/Path::Item
/Very/Long/Path::Item
Very/Very/Long/Path::Item
/Very/Very/Long/Path::Item
My/Very/Very/Long/Path::Item
```

There are stored into a **javascript** `Object`.
Now, I need to `.match()`, any of theses using the `full path` :

```
My/Very/Very/Long/Path::Item
```

This side is not the easier...

**I've tried :**

```
//NOTE : if it's match it returns 'OK'

var str = 'My/Very/Very/Long/Path';
var spltd = str.split('/');
var newstr = '('+spltd.join('/)?(')+')$';//alert(newstr);
var regex = new RegExp(newstr);
var check = str.match(regex);
console.log(check); // 'OK'
```

I can't say it doesn't work but it's still far to accurate. 
It returns '`OK`' in too-much cases....

Like when `str =`

```
My/Very/Long/Path::Item
My/Long/Path::Item
Very/Path::Item
etc.
```

Which is quite unacceptable.

Comment: because the path `My/Long/Path::Item` could eventually belong to another item. Then I need to preserve the hierarchy. But I want shortcuts.

Comment: Just Item should be accepted or not?

Comment: yes, if possible. But not a requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not pretty, but this Regex does the work:

```
^(?:\/?(?:(?:(?:(?:My\/)?Very\/)?Very\/)?Long\/)?Path::)?Item
```

You can change your code to this:

```
var str = 'My/Very/Very/Long/Path::Item';
var regex = new RegExp('^(?:\\/?(?:(?:(?:(?:My\\/)?Very\\/)?Very\\/)?Long\\/)?Path::)?Item');
var check = str.match(regex);
```

Tested on Regexr.com:

[image]

Note: If its a match it returns the match, not OK, and if its not a match it returns null

Comment: Genious. I had to adapt to match my number of element in path. I publish the solution in an EDIT into my post. ty @Rodrigo Lòpez

Comment: Oh, just saw what you did, your path was not fixed, good one, Cheers!